# Are there compatibility issues with Vaadin 6.8.12 and Liferay 6.2?

Tags: css, liferay-6, vaadin6

First time asking asking a question in here.  I'm deploying portlets on Liferay 6.2 and I'm using vaadin 6.8.12 and the portlets are showing up and they work properly but I'm having some styling issues.  I'm trying to figure out if there are compatibility issues with Vaadin 6.8.12 and Liferay 6.2 or if I have to go in and manually alter the css.

Comment: What kind of issues? Consider posting your codes and pointing out the problems in them, along with expected results.

Comment: Well I work in a confidential area so I don't think I can post the code but the issues that I'm having are issues with the color scheme being off for the most part.  We have old code that was done in Java 6 with Vaadin 6.7.3 on Liferay 5.0 that I'm comparing what I'm working on to and the color is just way off even though I've compared the stylesheets syntax to each other and they're the same

Comment: You don't have to post your real code with real data, just simulate your code context (*if I do this, I want that to happen, but instead, that other thing is happening*) and show us undesired outputs so we can have something to work with.

Comment: Hi, Do you find any solution our code CKeditor not working with Vaadin 6.8.12 and Liferay 6.2?